# Run UPDATE SET parameterized sql statement in Connection.execute sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to run a parametrized mysql UPDATE SET statement in flask_sqlalchemy. Since I do not know which columns should be updated I wrote a helper function to help in writing the statement.

My model

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement= True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

Helper function

```py
def run_sql(params):
    # e.g: params = {'username': "testing", "email": "testing@testing.ts", "id": 1}
    id = params.pop("id")
    # params = {'username': "testing", "email": "testing@testing.ts"}
    sets = list(map(lambda col: f"{col}=:{col}", params.keys()))
    # sets = ["username=:username", "email=:email"]
    sets = ", ".join(sets)
    # sets = "username=:username, email=:email"
    params["id"] = id
    # params = {'username': "testing", "email": "testing@testing.ts", "id": 1}
    sql_statement = f"""UPDATE User SET {sets} WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1"""
    # sql_statement = UPDATE User SET username=:username, email=:email WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1
    return  sql_statement
```

Calling helper function

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    conn = engine.connect()
    params = {'username': "testing", "email": "testing@testing.ts", "id": 1}
    sql_statement = run_sql(params)
    conn.execute(sql_statement, params)
```

Running the previous code generates the following exception

```
"sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':username, email=:email WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1' at line 1") [SQL: 'UPDATE User SET username=:username, email=:email WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1'] [parameters: {'username': 'testing', 'email': 'testing@testing.ts', 'id': 1}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)"
```

The SQL statement looks fine to me, so the parameters. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bind params aren't MySQL style, and as you're passing in plain text to `engine.execute()`, SQLAlchemy isn't applying a dialect to the query before executing it.

Try this:

```py
engine.execute("SELECT :val", {"val": 1})  # will fail, same as your query
```

...and then this:

```py
engine.execute("SELECT %(val)s", {"val": 1})  # will execute
```

Wrapping the query with `text()` will let SQLAlchemy handle the proper bind style:

```py
from sqlalchemy import text  # or you can use db.text w/ flask-sqlalchemy
engine.execute(text("SELECT :val"), {"val": 1})
```

One other thing to note is that SQLAlchemy will automatically handle construction of the UPDATE query for you, respecting the values in the parameter dict, e.g.:

```py
id_ = 1
params = {'username': "testing", "email": "testing@testing.ts"}
User.__table__.update().values(params).where(id=id_)
# UPDATE user SET username=%(username)s, email=%(email)s WHERE user.id = %(id_1)s

params = {'username': "testing"}
User.__table__.update().values(params).where(id=id_)
# UPDATE user SET username=%(username)s WHERE user.id = %(id_1)s

params = {'username': "testing", "unexpected": "value"}
User.__table__.update().values(params).where(id=id_)
# sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Unconsumed column names: unexpected
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the `:named_parameter` form for your SQL statement you'll need to use SQLAlchemy's `text` method and then call the `execute` method of a `Connection` object:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

# ...

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (id varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY)")
    sql = sa.text("INSERT INTO temp (id) VALUES (:id)")
    params = {'id': 'foo'}
    conn.execute(sql, params)

    print(conn.execute(sa.text("SELECT * FROM temp")).fetchall())  # [('foo',)]
```

Comment: This works for me, thank you! I will choose SuperShoot answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58801264/1321643 as the best answer as it explains the solution with more details.